# How to fix automatic shut off of my laptop

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

When I'm trying to turn on my laptop, before it finally reach the OS system (or the "Welcome" display in Windows), it shuts off (not shut down), it always the case when ever I try to open it.

I already clean the fan but it still gave the same results. When I start the laptop in safe mode, and other safe setting, it runs quite well but when it in normal mode, it shut off.

No viruses have been found during scans.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? Have you run virus and malware scans in Safe-Mode to make sure the computer is clean? Have done any research on this issue?

Comment: windows 7 sir,i already scan it, and no virus detected.

Comment: For clarification, when you say it "shuts off (not shut down)", do you mean it powers off?

Comment: yes, you're right sir.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter in Safe Mode, Windows starts with limited divers and none of the start up programs. Since your machine will boot in Safe Mode, but not normal, this indicates a program or driver is the likely cause of your issue.

To find out what is causing it, perform a [clean boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929135) and see if the issue still exists. If it is gone, slowly start re-enabling the items disabled previously. As soon as the problem comes back, the last thing enabled is what is causing it.